# Can I restrict a generic function to be called with primitive types and Strings only?

Tags: kotlin, generics

I have a function that assembles a URL with GET parameters, and it takes a parameter name of type `String` and currently a parameter value of type `Any?` on which it calls `toString()` if not `null`.

I want it to work only for types which can be meaningfully put into a URL (numbers, strings and booleans), and prevent people from calling it with any other object type.

Is this possible in Kotlin?

The usecase is that I tend to forget converting units to numbers when calling this function, and end up with `param=Angle(30,DEGREES)` where I really want `param=30`.

Comment: Unfortunately, a direct solution would require union types, which Kotlin doesn't (yet?) support.

Answer (score 5):

If it is just a single function, you can use overloads for this:

```kotlin
private fun yourFunction(param: Any?){
    //your code
}

fun yourFunction(param: String?) = yourFunction(param as? Any?)
fun yourFunction(param: Int?) = yourFunction(param as? Any?)
fun yourFunction(param: Boolean?) = yourFunction(param as? Any?)
//the same for other types
```

At first, create your function with `Any?` as you already do but make it private.

For every allowed type, add an overload with that type. That overload just calls the `Any?`-overload.

If [Union types](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13108/Denotable-union-and-intersection-types) are available in some future Kotlin version, you could use those as @[Tenfour04](https://stackoverflow.com/users/506796/tenfour04) mentioned in the comments of your question but Union types are not a Kotlin feature at the time of writing.

Comment: Please note that casting with `param as Any?` will throw an exception when the `param` is null. Use `param as? Any?` to be sure.

Comment: Hm. Or maybe I can take the parameter as a `reified ParamType` and do some compile-time checks on that?

Comment: @FelixDombek theoretically, you could use KSP or similar tools for compile-time checks (though not on runtime values of generic types) but it would be possible to write code that does not run these checks.

Comment: It seems to also work if I omit the `as? Any?` completely.

Comment: This is correct since every kotlin class derived from `Any` and the argument is marked as nullable.

Comment: @FelixDombek the `as? Any?` is required if youbuse overloads (the method being named the same) because omitting would result in recursion and a `StackOverflowError` at runtime.

Comment: Ah, makes sense -- I named the `Any?` function differently. Thanks :) Btw, I think `Int` should be `Number` in your example, so that this function works with doubles, longs etc.

Comment: You can add as many types as you want.

Comment: I can, but is there any benefit creating an overload for each number type as opposed to one overload which takes `Number`?

Comment: @FelixDombek If you can handle any `Number` implementation, then there's no benefit. But if you can only handle certain types of `Number`, then you'll want an overload for each one. Note that `Number` also includes things like `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal` (from Java), and that's ignoring third-party implementations of `Number`.

Answer (score 2):

You can only have one upper bound for a generic type. Meaning that `String OR Number` is not possible as of time of writing.

@dan1st pointed out that [Union types](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13108/Denotable-union-and-intersection-types) may be the preferable solution to your problem.

However you can use these attempt to solve your issue:

- Createing overloading method signatures where every type can be handled

  ```kotlin
  fun makeUrl(path: String, parameter: String): MyUrl = downstreamUrlBuilder(path, parameter)
  fun makeUrl(path: String, parameter: Number): MyUrl = downstreamUrlBuilder(path, parameter.toString())
  ```
- Creating a data access object that contains useful url information.

  ```kotlin
  data class UrlParameter(val value: Any?) {
     init {
         if(value !is String && !is Number) throw IllegalArgumentException("reason")
     }
  }

  fun makeUrl(path: String, parameter: UrlParameter): MyUrl { TODO() }
  ```

Comment: Would the second idea be possible at compile time by doing something like a static assert on a reified generic type?

Comment: A generic reified type can not be checked at compile time out of the box when using Any as upper bound. Libraries like Arrow have such tools to annotate methods and make additional compile type checks. I would prefer the method overload strategy over DAOs but in depends on the whole picture